# Upper bound for the reciprocal of a sum involving Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, mobius-function

For  $ n $ an integer greater than  $ 6 $ , let  $ Q(n)=\prod_{p\leq\sqrt{2n-3}}p $.

Which upper bound in terms of  $ n $ can we get for  $ (\sum_{d\mid Q(n)}\frac{\mu(d)}{d})^{-1} $?

Comment: The sum is $\prod_{p\leq{\sqrt{2n-3}}}(1-1/p)$. Use the Mertens' theorems. I also don't see much point of using $\sqrt{2n-3}$, your $Q(n)$ is just $x\#$ for $x=\sqrt{2n-3}$.

Comment: Thank you. This gives an upper bound equal to $O(\log n) $.

Comment: This even gives you exact asymptotics as well as error term, but if you just want an upper bound, yes, it's $O(\log n)$.

Comment: The asymptotics you refer to is  $\frac{e^{\gamma}}{2}\log 2n $ right ?

Comment: Right. The $2n$ could be replaced by $n$ too, since $\log 2n\sim\log n$.

Comment: Indeed but it is numerically less accurate.

Comment: I suppose; guess that depends on what purposes you need the bound for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88973/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-wojowu).